# How to say "thank you for this awesome/amazing video" in French and sound like a native?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, orthographe

I just watched a video on Youtube by this guy: [Antoine BM](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUyGfgvkPXfV80exjZIqmVQ). I watch him because he helps me with my learning French.

I want to comment on one of his newest videos. What can I say?

> génial video

> très bon video

Can you tell me of other more interesting and kind things to comment under a youtube video that a native would say?

Comment: first, the adjective "génial" goes after the name, and not before. Secondly, "vidéo" takes an "é" in French, and it is feminine ("la vidéo" and not "le vidéo") so, since you must agree "génial" with "vidéo", then you must say "vidéo géniale". the same agreement goes for "bon", but "bon" is placed before the noun (this placement of the adjective is a big difficulty of French): "très bonne vidéo".

Comment: I'm adding some remarks about the placement of adjectives:
first, the placement does not depend on the name, but on the adjective itself: for exampe, colours are placed after the name, but common adjectives of size are placed before:
"une petite maison", "une grande maison", "une maison blanche", "une maison bleue"
In poetry, you can do what you want: In a poem, you could find "une rouge maison", but you will never find it in current life and not even in prose, where it will always be "une maison rouge".

Comment: merci pour votre aide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Merci pour cette vidéo géniale !

> Excellente vidéo, merci !